# WebView not scaling correctly?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-imageview

I'm using a WebView to convert an HTML to an image. The HTML has a fixed with of 600px (defined using CSS).

The WebView layout is:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

On loading the html document, I get the webview size by doing:

```
int width = webView.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = webView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

The first weird thing that I notice is that the width is 650. The document is displayed and I need to scroll horizontally to view it all (lo-res device).

The next step is to convert the webview into an image:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
webView.draw(c);
```

However, converting the webview into the bitmap crops off the right part (the area where is not visible in the webview).

Why is the webview width 650 when I defined 600 in my HTML document? And why is imaged cropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that HTML (CSS) pixels are not the same as screen pixels. This is because you can scale the page that you are viewing -- this won't affect its CSS dimensions (simply speaking, HTML layout will not "notice" scaling), but will rather change how many screen pixels you have in your CSS pixel.

When you are calling `WebView.draw()` for an on-screen WebView, it draws onto the canvas according to the current size of WebView -- basically, what you see on the screen is what you will get in your bitmap.

Thus, there are two ways to do what you want:

1. Make WebView width big enough to accommodate your page. For this, you need to put WebView inside a `ScrollView`, and set the width of WebView accordingly.
2. Size the displayed content so it fits on the screen. For that, you can use two WebView settings: `setUseWideViewport(true)` and `setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)`, and `initial-scale` value in `<meta name="viewport">` HTML tag.